# Can't bind to 'someProperty' since it isn't a known property of 'someComponent' in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, binding, components, angular5

In Angular 5 app I'm using following component:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  forwardRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'int-switcher',
  templateUrl: './switcher.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./switcher.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SwitcherComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class SwitcherComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() _value: boolean;
  get value() {
      return this._value;
  }
  set value(val) {
      this._value = val;
      this.propagateChange(this._value);
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this._value = value;
    }
  }
  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
      this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}
  toggleValue() {
    this.value = !this.value;
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }
}
```

And template:

```
<div class="switcher" (click)="toggleValue()">
  <div class="switcher-label"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
  <div class="switch">
    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="value">
    <label class="switch-label switch-paddle"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set the value for this property, but I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of
>   'int-switcher'.
>
> 1. If 'int-switcher' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'int-switcher' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

I have tried to do the following:

```
<int-switcher name="groupHotel" formControlName="groupHotel" (click)="setGrouping($event)" [value]="isGrouped">
```

and in ngInit:

```
  isGrouped: boolean;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isGrouped = true;
}
```

Why can't I bind to this property?

Answer (score -1):

Your @Input is set to underscore value, not `@Input value`, your issue lies there. You want to make sure your `@Input <name>` matches with what you use when you use your component/directive.

Simplest untested example;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'color-component',
  template: `<div>{{color}}</div>` 
})
export class ColorComponent {
  @Input() color: string;
}
```

then when you use the component

```
<color-component [color]="blue"</color-component>
```